# What happened to the website https://mechon-mamre.org/?

Tags: internet

I was regularly in contact with friends on this website, but I realized that their email mtr@mechon-mamre.org no longer works. Do you know what happened?

Comment: This question is unfortunately not appropriate for Mi Yodeya. It's also not quite clear what you are asking. The website works but that specific email doesn't?

Comment: I VTC because this has nothing to do with judaism per se.

Comment: Maybe they left? How would we know? This being said, good to see you back

Comment: I don't understand your surprise. It's a site of Jewish scholars of the Jewish tradition, their email suddenly doesn't work anymore, I simply asked if anyone knows the reason!

Comment: @Amos74 no surprised, except the pleasant surprise of hearing from you. It's not a bad question at all, it just doesn't belong here. Note, I just sent an email to that address and didn't get any error

Comment: you are right, the email has changed but I didn't notice, I always read the old one. Thank you!

Comment: I reopened because I thought at first that this question was about the online Judaism resource. I then closed it again when I realized that it's about trying to get in touch with some people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last updated version of the website of Mechon Mamre seems to be of 8 March 2023.

Maybe since then, they are using the following email-adress as per their site (under "write us!":

> mechon.mamre.org@gmail.com

[image]

Comment: you are right, the email has changed but I didn't notice, I always read the old one. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to be of help and it was certainly not a bad question, but just not about the Judaism-part this site is about. Nevertheless, I hope it helped you.